# How to have Dexy evaluate Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, dexy

The dexy documentation states than any language may be used. The tutorial use the `py` filter to run Python file, but I didn't find any filter to run Perl file.

I try to execute a very simple Perl file

I've tried to use the `bash` or `sh` filter, but with no luck, and didn't find any `execute`-or-like filter.

Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: ~14 hours ago a "Perl filter" was added on github https://github.com/dexy/dexy/commit/63903b62476376c750d39b24a2520d51861468a4

Comment: Yes, just after I talk with Ana about this. She's very talented AND reactive. :) I'll write an answer below with various solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here are the different solutions I found about this.

**1. A perl filter now exist**

Ok, Ana is the owner of this project and is very reactive. I asked her the question about dexy and perl on IRC, and tada ! Less than 1 hour later, there was a commit on the repository with perl support.

So, if you just get latest version and install it this way :

```
git clone https://github.com/dexy/dexy
cd dexy
sudo pip install -e .
```

You should have a `perl` filter.
If you want to pass arguments to a script, just use the `scriptargs` setting.

**2. Use a bash script**

Another very simple solution is to embed the launch of a perl script into a sh/bash script, and use the sh/shint/bash filter that already exist.

**3. Use bash script without additional files**

If you fear that the latest solution will makes you add a lot of tiny scripts in your directories, you may use the `contents` feature of dexy. That way, the required one-liners are defined in `dexy.yaml` only.
Something like :

```
- shell-myscript.sh|sh:
   - contents: "perl ./perl/myscript.pl --any-parameter"
   - perl/myscript.pl
```

is doing the job just fine for me.